# What is the new lightbox hotness?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Lightbox2?
Fancybox?

Specifically, one that I could use with jquery.

Comment: Subjective and will probably be closed. Why not look at the examples on their websites and decide which one *you* like best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like to use jqModal, http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/, as it is not specifically a lightbox but more a utility to display notices, dialog boxes, and modals (a lightbox).  It is lightweight and simple to use so you spend less time learning what you can and cannot do with it.  As far as the look and feel, it's up to you to customize the creative so it gives more power to the developer and doesn't box you into something.